# Sitecore item:created vs item:added

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

What is the difference between the events `item:created` vs `item:added`? When does each event get hit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the code of the Sitecore.Data.Events.ItemAddedDelegate you may read that this delegate is deprecated and you should use ItemCreatedDelegate instead. From my tests:

1. Creating new item - both item:added and item:created are executed
2. Cloning item - both item:added and item:created are executed
3. Duplicating item - item:added is NOT executed, only item:created is executed

   ```
   namespace Sitecore.Data.Events
   {
       [Obsolete("Use the ItemCreatedDelegate event instead.")]
       public delegate void ItemAddedDelegate(object sender, ItemAddedEventArgs args);
   }
   ```

So in general, always use item:created

Comment: Hmm... the only thing being that when item:created is executed, the notifications of the cloned items are not generated.

Comment: Great tip to use the `ItemCreatedDelegate` to look for the signature!

Answer (score 3):

> The item:added and item:created events seem similar, but Sitecore only
>   fires item:added when a user creates an item through the UI, but it
>   fires fires item:created when code creates items through APIs. Use
>   item:added if you only need to trap manual item additions.

Reference: Taken from John West's blog post

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-events-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms